# Salida retardada document.write hasta fin del bucle while con prompt

Tags: javascript, while, bucles

Se trata de leer con un `prompt` un valor y seguir pidiéndolo hasta que el valor introducido sea 5. Me gustaría mostrar con `document.write` el valor introducido aunque no sea el buscado. Utilizo un bucle `while` y sólo me muestra todos los valores introducidos una vez que salgo del bucle. Esto me pasa en `Chrome`, en `Firefox` funciona como espero. A ver si alguien me da una idea ya que estoy todavía empezando con `JS`. Gracias.

```js
 var valido = 5;
 var valorusuario = 0;
 while (valorusuario!=valido) {
   valorusuario = parseInt(prompt("Introduce un número entre 1 y 10"));
   document.write("Tu número es ", valorusuario,"<br>");
 }
 document.write("Has acertado el número !!!");
```

Comment: Lo primero decir que insertar contenido HTML con document.write se considera una mala práctica ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice]).

En cuanto a por qué en Firefox "funciona" se debe a que, al no existir una especificación, cada navegador lo implementa de distinta forma. ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398005/why-document-write-behaves-differently-in-firefox-and-chrome]). Mi recomendación es que utilices otros métodos de manipulación del DOM como createElement y appendChild:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que la ejecución de Javascript *bloquea* todo lo demás en la pantalla, por lo que hasta que no termine el bucle de tu código, el *engine* de HTML no se pone en marcha para actualizar la vista con el nuevo DOM.
La solución es usar setTimeout para crear una especie de bucle mediante recursividad:

```js
var valido = 5;

function pideNumero() {
  let valorUsuario = parseInt(prompt("Introduce un número entre 1 y 10"));
  let p = document.createElement("p");
  p.innerHTML=`Tu número es ${valorUsuario}`;
  document.body.appendChild(p);
  if (valorUsuario != valido) {
    setTimeout(pideNumero,10);
  } else {
    p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerHTML='Has acertado el número!';
    document.body.appendChild(p);
  }
}
setTimeout(pideNumero)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Es bastante curioso que en Firefox funcione y en Chrome no. Tomo nota de tu contribución.

Comment: Curioso, porque yo uso Chrome (en GNU/Linux) y funciona bien

Comment: Si te refieres a tu código, Firefox es ahora más *multihilo* que Chrome, tiene un hilo para el render separado

Comment: Sí, me refería a mi código. El tuyo va perfecto. Gracias.

Comment: Puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada para dejar tu pregunta como *respondida*, si así te parece